переход на пустую страницу при выводе карточек товара через записи с помощью ACF в WordPress
такая ситуация, вывожу карточки новостей на страницу по категориям использую AFC, создаю группу полей указываю тип записи - запись в условиях отображения, потом к этой записи(карточке) прилинковываю страницу самой новости.
Проблема: пост(запись) который создается ведет на пустую страницу при нажатии "Просмотреть запись" из админки. То есть при нажатии на каточку на сайте со стороны пользователя все ок, переходит на страницу новости, которую я прилинковал вручную(сделал отдельное поле в шаблоне записи), но эта пустая страница она существует и я так понимаю это не очень хорошо в плане SEO да и вообще глобально.
Перерыл гугл не нашел ничего. Подскажите, пожалуйста как эти вещи делать по нормальному?
Спасибо

Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно.

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress
